# Segue and Unwind segue without UI element

Tags: swift, segue, unwind-segue

I have been looking for an answer for this on SO without success.

I have `UIViewController` A and B. They are NOT linked in Storyboard, and I want to perform a `Segue` from A to B, and upon clicking a button in B, to activate an `unwindSegue` to A.

So far I have :

1) The `@IBAction` in A to unwind back to 
2) The function to prepare the Segue from A to B (In A)
3) The button to call the `unwindSegue` from B to A

What I'm missing is the logic of the function in 2.

More info about B:

Title: FilterView
Class: FilterViewController
Storyboard ID: FilterView

I tried creating a segue:

```
let segueToFilter = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "SegueToFilterView", source: self, destination: FilterViewController)
```

Thinking this might just get me what I need.

but I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'FilterViewController.Type' to expected argument type UIViewController
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What stops you from adding a segue in the storyboard?

Comment: I have several UIViewControllers that can segue to it and I do not want to add like 3-4 visual segues

Comment: Then you should just call the `present` and `dismiss` methods to do this, without segues.

Comment: So how do I activate a method after dismiss ? And how do I transfer info to the screen to show up after dismiss ?

Comment: _"I do not want to add like 3-4 visual segues"_ why not?

Comment: @Sweeper Actually it runs deeper than this, I CAN add a visual segue but I will need to remove 2 of the 3 ViewControllers I have which might be a headache as this time

Comment: @AshleyMills I want to keep it as clean as possible... Actually there might be something I might be able to do but I will need guidance in this (Removing 2 of the 3 views which inherit from the same view)

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by _"keep it as clean as possible"_. How does adding a segue in the storyboard make it "unclean". If it's a problem with unwind methods in a superclass, how about adding the unwind Action to your subclasses rather than your superclass?

Comment: @AshleyMills

I think I will address the bigger picture here and try to remove s creens. I will edit question soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not understand how segues are causing problems to you, but if you *really* *really* don't want to use segues, you can try presenting and dismissing VCs programmatically.

The idea goes like this:

- Create an instance of your VC
- Pass data to it by setting some properties
- Present!
- In the VC, dismiss.

The actual code will be different if you embedded your VCs in a navigation controller. Instead of calling `present` and `dismiss`, you would call `pushVC` and `popVC` on the navigation controller.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterView") as FilterViewController
vc.someProperty = someData // this is where you pass data
vc.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To pass data back, you should use the delegate pattern by creating a `FilterViewDelegate` that the first VC conforms to. Look up on Google for more info.

Comment: Thank you :) You also made me realize I should address the bigger picture here, and so I will soon post a new question